# I am trying to figure out how to 1.) Graph the polar curve and 2.) Find the area that encloses it on Mathematica

Tags: plotting

r= Sqrt(1+(cos(5theta))^2)

I am not sure on how to graph and find the area of this in Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)
 now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png)
, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
, and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: A very brief comment. Built-in functions in mathematica are capiotalized, i.e `cos` should be `Cos`. There should also be a space between `5` and `theta`, otherwise Mathematica recognizes `5theta` as one variable. Also, what did you try in order to plot this function?

Comment: I have tried PolarPlot[Sqrt[1 + (Cos ((5 \[Theta]))^2)], {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi} ]
but nothing will output.

Comment: You have the following mistakes. `[Theta]` should not be like that. Also it should be `Cos[whatever you want in here]` and not with parentheses. Execute `PolarPlot[Sqrt[1 + (Cos[(5 theta)]^2)], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]` to get a plot

Comment: Ok that worked thanks for that but how do I code it to where I could find the area for it?

Comment: General advice: if you want to write Greek letters, you can do for example `esc`, then type `theta` and type `esc` again. Another simple solution would be to add the Greek language o your keyboard, so you can typeset Greek characters directly into Mma. Either one or the other will help you avoid the previous mistake.

Comment: The area of a curve is just an integral. It is not a question on Mma software. There is a built-in command that is called `Integrate`

Comment: Integrate[Sqrt[1 + (Cos[5 theta])^2], 2 Pi]. Ok so I am doing this but it is still not giving an output. Could you see what the mistake is that I am doing?

Comment: Did you look up the syntax for `Integrate`? You have neither specified which is the variable that you want to integrate nor its domain. Try to execute `Integrate[Sqrt[1 + (Cos[5 theta])^2], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]` to get an answer in terms of an elliptic integral

Comment: you can have a look at [Integrate with Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html)

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong I had to use theta instead of 2Pi. Thanks for all of the help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

- In the polar coordinate, to calculate its area which enclose by  `r[θ]=Sqrt[1 + Cos[5 θ]^2`, we need to use
  $$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} r(\theta)^2 \,\mathrm{d}\theta$$

instead of $\int_0^{\pi}r(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$.

## Integral calculus (area)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

```
r[θ_] = Sqrt[1 + (Cos[5 θ])^2];
Integrate[1/2 r[θ]^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

> `(3 π)/2`

- If we translate the `Polar` codrdinate to `Cartesian` coordinate,we can also use Green formula to calculate such area.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter

```
x[θ_] = r[θ]*Cos[θ];
y[θ_] = r[θ]*Sin[θ];
1/2 Integrate[x'[θ]*y[θ]-x[θ]*y'[θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}]// Abs
```

> `(3 π)/2`

- To draw such region we can introduce the variable `t`, `0<=t<=1`.

```
r[θ_] = Sqrt[1 + (Cos[5 θ])^2];
ParametricPlot[t*r[θ] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
polarplot = PolarPlot[Sqrt[1 + Cos[5 θ]^2], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to replace the `Line` object with a `Polygon`:

```
polygon = polarplot /. Line -> Polygon
```

[image]

Use [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.html) to get a [`Region`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html) object:

```
region = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @ polygon
```

[image]

Use [`Area`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Area.html) or [`RegionMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) to the area:

```
Area @ region
```

> ```
> 4.71218
> ```

```
RegionMeasure @ region
```

> ```
> 4.71218
> ```

You can also extract the line from `polarplot`, replace it with a polygon and get its area in  single step using [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html):

```
First @ Cases[polarplot, Line[x_] :> Area[Polygon @ x], All]
```

> ```
> 4.71218
> ```

Answer (score 0):

PolarPlot[Sqrt[1 + (Cos[(5 theta)]^2)], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
Integrate[Sqrt[1 + (Cos[5 theta])^2], theta]

Comment: The integrand is not correct, I believe.  Evaluate it and compare to other answers.